# Allowing admin to modify email address with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise to manage users. I would like to allow an admin to edit users information, and that includes the email address. Here's what I have in my users_controller:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.confirmed_at = nil
  #@user.save(:validate => false)
  @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
end
```

The problem that all the fields in the form update fine, but not the email field. How can I have it update the email field? Obviously, I would not want a conformation email going to the end user (in this case, an admin had temporary emails in the DB, and would like to edit them to reflect the real emails).

Comment: Why do you save the record two times, including one time without validation?

Comment: Some of the records were initially saved with a temporary email address, and no confirmation was sent. Now an admin wants to go into the DB and enter the correct email addresses, without causing a confirmation email to be sent out.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read the comment carefully. The first save is not needed, I will remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [source](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#update_without_password-instance_method).

`update_without_password` method deletes `:email` from `params`. So, to update `email`, you should do, for example:

```
def update
  # code
  @user.update_column(:email, params[:user].delete(:email))
  @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
end
```

Comment: This did not work. The email field did not get updated, but a confirmation email was generated. I want the email field to get updated, without a confirmation going out.

Comment: Was the confirmation email sent when you was calling `@user.save(validate: false)`?

Comment: Ok I edited the answer - now new email should be saved without callbacks and validations.

Comment: This was working fine yesterday, and all of sudden, the first statement executes (@user.update_column(:email, params[:user].delete(:email)) but the statement following that does not (updating other changes to the record). I have a redirect statement after that, and it's executing fine. Any idea why the second statement is skipped?

Comment: I am using the same piece of code for this method, and that's the odd part. It's executing the first statement, skipping the second, then executing the redirect which comes after that.

Comment: Problem fixed. I forgot that I added some attr_write to the model as I was trying something out. I removed them and I'm back in business.

Comment: That's good. I advice you to use version control system to prevent this kinds of bugs. :)